# Using XSL/XPath to match nodes with any name having a given attribute and child-node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to use XPath/XSLT to add a node to an existing node that fulfills certain requirements:

- The node has an attribute "id"
- The node has a child named "Type", containing a given text, e.g. "Identifier"

In XML to match:

```
  <SomeRandomNode>
    <Type>SomeRandomType</Type>
    <Child>
      <Count type="int32">2</Count>       
      <!-- This node should be matched -->
      <Key id="5">
        <Type>Identifier</Type>
        <SomeValue type="string">Hello</SomeValue>
        <SomeOtherValue type="string">World</SomeOtherValue>
      </Key>
    </Child>
  </SomeRandomNode>
</Project>
```

I'm having a hard time writing the match expression for this, my "best" attempt being:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@id][.//Typename='Identifier']"> 
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
    </xsl:attribute>

    <!-- Copy nodes -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="Type" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="SomeValue" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="SomeOtherValue" />
    <!-- Add new -->
    <NewValue type="string">This node was added</NewValue>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If I replace the * with a nodename it works fine, but I need to match nodes with any name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template match is looking for descendant `Typename` elements, you want to look for `Type` elements.

Also, you are currently matching for descendants, but your question and template logic are looking for child elements.

**You should adjust your template match to:**

```
*[@id][Type='Identifier']
```

Answer (score 2):

The `*` should work fine. But you're matching against the element `Typename` instead of `Type` in your example, so try this:

```
*[@id][Type='Identifier']
```

Or:

```
*[@id and (Type='Identifier')]
```